# Looping through pictures in picturebox and adding its name to combobox?

Tags: vb.net, loops, combobox, picturebox

I have around 20 pictures in picturebox and i want to loop through all images and add it's name to a combobox then i use the combobox to change the picture in the picturebox. I Dont know how to loop through picturebox images.

for example..these names
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To populate a ComboBox with images from resources :

```
   For Each dicEntry As DictionaryEntry In resourceSet.OfType(Of Object)()
        If TypeOf (dicEntry.Value) Is Drawing.Image Then
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(dicEntry.Key.ToString())              
        End If
   Next
```

To select the image and set it to a PictureBox :

```
 Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
     Dim comboBox As ComboBox = CType(sender, ComboBox)
     Dim sSelectedItem = CType(comboBox.SelectedItem, String)
     Dim img As Image = CType(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(sSelectedItem), Image)
     PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = img
 End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify a folder inside resources folder?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to address here. Most importantly, `Image` objects don't have a name, so there's nothing to list.  Maybe you mean the names of the files that the `Image` objects were created from, but that's something different.  You won't be able to get those from the `PictureBox` controls unless you set the `ImageLocation` properties to load the files. Assuming that you have done that, you could get the name of each file from the `PictureBoxes` like this:

```
Dim fileNames = Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox)().
                         Select(Function(pb) IO.Path.GetFileName(pb.ImageLocation))
```

That still doesn't really make sense though.  It seems like getting the names of the files before loading the `Images` would make more sense.  You haven't really explained enough to provide a confident solution though.

Comment: Your update is of no value.  There's no indication of what the relationship is between the list of names you have displayed and the `Images` you describe.  You've addressed nothing that I raised in my answer.